# custom page.tpl.php for a drupal view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views, drupal-themes

How can I create a custom page.tpl.php for a specific view?

I'm not talking about styling the view itself, just the page where that view gets rendered.

Thank you.

@Keith Morgan - It's page.

Comment: The approach depends on what kind of view display you are working with. Is it page or block for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a template file to theme almost any aspect of views output. In your case you want to create a custom template for your page display.

On the view designer, click the Theme link in Basic Settings. You'll see some template file naming options depending on if you want to theme the whole view (e.g., views-view--example--page.tpl.php), each row (e.g., views-view-fields--example--page.tpl.php) and so on.

Copy the appropriate template you want to customize from /sites/all/modules/views/theme to your theme and customize as you wish.

Once you create your custom template file, you can go back to the view designer Theme link to make sure it is being used. Your template should be bolded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't the OP asking about theming the page when a view is active and not the view itself?  When you have a view with a page display, the topmost template is still derived from views-view.tpl.php, which doesn't include any page elements.  This still gets stuffed into the whatever page template is active.

Answer (score 7):

Per Allartk's solution
In Drupal 7 template.php:

```
function <theme>_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (($views_page = views_get_page_view()) && $views_page->name === "galleries") {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__views__galleries';
    }
}
```

Then in your theme directory, create the page--views--galleries.tpl.php file.
Clear drupal cache and template should work.
I used 'galleries' as and example views name.

Comment: No need for this, just use `drupal 7 is page--path-to-view.tpl.php`

Comment: @Duncanmoo - the advantage to Amir's approach is that you can explicitly see that the template contains a view, if naming convention concerns you (just like we have page--node-mynode.tpl.php for instance). I like to combine similar to the above with using the view's machine name, so that, for instance if my view exists here/there/myview, I can have page--view--myview.tpl.php, rather than the standard page--here--there--myview.tpl.php

Answer (score 4):

There's some [documentation on template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440), and you might be interested in [page.tpl.php suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/190815#page-suggestion). If it's a page view, you could use a path suggestion. So if your view is at http://www.example.com/photos, the `page.tpl.php` file would be named `page-photos.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem, which was remedied by putting a .tpl.php in my theme's template folder. The naming convention for a page display of views in drupal 7 is page--path-to-view.tpl.php

Answer (score 2):

In a drupal 7 theme I added a template suggestion in template.php:

```
function sovon_preprocess_page(&$variables) {   
if(views_get_page_view())   {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__view';      
}
}
```

See http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/views_get_page_view/7 and http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions for more information.

Comment: I liked the simplicity of your answer, but I figured I'd build on it.  I also realize that it's over two years old, but this may help.  So, what I did was change the inside of the function to be this:  

if($view = views_get_page_view())   {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page--view-'.$view->name;
}

What this does is grabs the view name and looks for any template files with the prefix of "page--view-" and your view name.  This way you can extend this without writing an if statment for each view.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a view as a page, you can use the results of `page_manager_get_current_page()` in your preprocess to determine if your view is active, then take the appropriate steps (tack on body classes, add a template suggestion, etc).

Answer (score 1):

using sillygwailo's suggestion I got this to work for me very nicely:

```
function YOUR-THEME-NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

 //allow template suggestions based on url paths.  
 $alias = drupal_get_path_alias(str_replace('/edit','',$_GET['q'])); 
 if ($alias != $_GET['q']) { $suggestions = array();
 $template_filename = 'page'; 
 foreach (explode('/', $alias) as $path_part) {
 $template_filename = $template_filename . '-' . $path_part; 
 $suggestions[] = $template_filename;
 } 
 $alias_array = explode('/', $alias);
 $variables['template_files'] = $suggestions;
```

Then if your view is at www.example.com/photos , create a page-photos.tpl.php in your theme directory and drupal will use that as your template.

Answer (score 0):

If that checked answer doesnt work(because it didnt for me) you can create a page--(urlname).tpl.php and then style your theme however you want it.  Then you can import your view in one of several ways ...

```
       print render($page['content']);
```

or

$view = views_get_view('viewname');
   print $view->execute_display('default', $args);

$args is just an array and can be blank..you can just leave it off entirely